# Mock out imported Lazy React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, javascript-import, react-suspense

Here's my lazy component:

```
const LazyBones = React.lazy(() => import('@graveyard/Bones')
  .then(module => ({default: module.BonesComponent}))
export default LazyBones
```

I'm importing it like this:

```
import Bones from './LazyBones'

export default () => (
<Suspense fallback={<p>Loading bones</p>}>
  <Bones />
</Suspense>
)
```

And in my test I have this kind of thing:

```
import * as LazyBones from './LazyBones';

describe('<BoneYard />', function() {
  let Bones;
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(function() {
    Bones = sinon.stub(LazyBones, 'default');
    Bones.returns(() => (<div />));
    wrapper = shallow(<BoneYard />);
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    Bones.restore();
  });

  it('renders bones', function() {
    console.log(wrapper)
    expect(wrapper.exists(Bones)).to.equal(true);
  })

})
```

What I expect is for the test to pass, and the console.log to print out:

```
<Suspense fallback={{...}}>
  <Bones />
</Suspense>
```

But instead of `<Bones />` I get `<lazy />` and it fails the test.

How can I mock out the imported Lazy React component, so that my simplistic test passes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the answer you're looking for, but it sounds like part of the problem is `shallow`. According to [this thread](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2212#issuecomment-576941420), `shallow` won't work with `React.lazy`.

However, `mount` also doesn't work when trying to stub a lazy component - if you debug the DOM output (with `console.log(wrapper.debug())`) you can see that `Bones` is in the DOM, but it's the real (non-stubbed-out) version.

The good news: if you're only trying to check that `Bones` exists, you don't have to mock out the component at all! This test passes:

```
import { Bones } from "./Bones";
import BoneYard from "./app";

describe("<BoneYard />", function() {
  it("renders bones", function() {
    const wrapper = mount(<BoneYard />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.exists(Bones)).to.equal(true);
    wrapper.unmount();
  });
});
```

If you do need to mock the component for a different reason, `jest` will let you do that, but it sounds like you're trying to avoid `jest`. [This thread](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1917) discusses some other options in the context of `jest` (e.g. 
 [mocking `Suspense` and `lazy`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1917#issuecomment-465198684)) which may also work with `sinon`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real bones component has to be stubbed as it contains an es6 import. But this is a good answer for everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to resolve `lazy()` function by using `.then(x => x.default)` React already does that for you.

> React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This must return a Promise which resolves to a module with a default export containing a React component. [React code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

Syntax should look something like:

```js
const LazyBones = React.lazy(() => import("./LazyBones"))
```

**Example:**

```js
// LazyComponent.js
import React from 'react'

export default () => (
  <div>
    <h1>I'm Lazy</h1>
    <p>This component is Lazy</p>
  </div>
)

// App.js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
// This will import && resolve LazyComponent.js that located in same path
const LazyComponent = lazy(() => import('./LazyComponent'))

// The lazy component should be rendered inside a Suspense component
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <LazyComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit react-lazy-component-test]

---

As for **Testing**, you can follow the React testing example that shipped by default within `create-react-app` and change it a little bit.

Create a new file called `LazyComponent.test.js` and add:

```js
// LazyComponent.test.js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

const LazyComponent = lazy(() => import('./LazyComponent'))

test('renders lazy component', async () => {
  // Will render the lazy component
  render(
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  )
  // Match text inside it
  const textToMatch = await screen.findByText(/I'm Lazy/i)
  expect(textToMatch).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

**Live Example:** Click on the **Tests** Tab just next to **Browser** tab. if it doesn't work, just reload the page.

[image: Edit react-lazy-component-testing]

You can find more [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#more-examples) complex examples at their [Docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-codesandbox) website.

Comment: Is this not possible using sinon? I'd rather not have to convince my team to change 1000+ tests so I can cover one thing.

Comment: Sure it's possible, those examples are just to get the idea, you can follow the same principle and do more complex ones. maybe [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-shape-g0dvs?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.spec.js&previewwindow=tests) will help a bit.

Comment: I've had a look and I can't find an equivalent in sinon. As such 'Use a different testing library' is not useful.

Comment: @Pureferret you can use directly the jest.spyOn to spy behavior of object like jest.spyOn(props, 'onChange'). Otherwise, keep in mind that the jest.fn() return a object with properties like sinon.

Comment: @xargr I'm not using jest (unfortunately). And this answer doesn't involve jest. I'm not sure why you're bringing it up?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to test my lazy component using Enzyme. Following approach worked for me to test on component loading completion:

```
const myComponent = React.lazy(() => 
      import('@material-ui/icons')
      .then(module => ({ 
         default: module.KeyboardArrowRight 
      })
   )
);
```

Test Code ->

```
//mock actual component inside suspense
jest.mock("@material-ui/icons", () => { 
    return {
        KeyboardArrowRight: () => "KeyboardArrowRight",
}
});

const lazyComponent = mount(<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
           {<myComponent>}
       </Suspense>);
    
const componentToTestLoaded  = await componentToTest.type._result; // to get actual component in suspense
    
expect(componentToTestLoaded.text())`.toEqual("KeyboardArrowRight");
```

This is hacky but working well for Enzyme library.

Comment: How do you do this in Sinon?

Answer (score -3):

To mock you lazy component first think is to transform the test to asynchronous and wait till component exist like:

```
import CustomComponent, { Bones } from './Components';

it('renders bones', async () => {
   const wrapper = mount(<Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
                       <CustomComponent />
                   </Suspense>

   await Bones;
   expect(wrapper.exists(Bones)).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Comment: this has no effect on the results of my mounted component